# Perfom a task when my app restored from background

Tags: android

I need to do some network request when user restores my app from background (for example: worked with app - pressed home button - home screen - switched to my app again via task manager or clicked app icon). I don't want this to be triggered by screen rotate or simple change of current activity by startActivity(). What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Override the [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Your work goes here
}
```

`onResume()` will be called when the user returns to the Activity.

Comment: It will be triggered when activity is created first time, when it recreates after screen rotation etc. I need to catch only the moment when user returns to the already running app from background.

Comment: You could define a variable that will be set in `onPause()` and you check for that variable before you do your work in `onResume()`. However, It is _for sure_ not a perfect solution.